# python - sum of float causes repeating decimal

Tags: python

I am trying to sum up a list of float number. There is not repeating decimals in the list but the result is a repeating decimals number. What is the cause and how to prevent? (Python version: 2.7.11)

For example,

```
a=[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1]
sum(a)
```

results in

```
7.699999999999999
```

Thank you.

Comment: This happens because computers have a limited amount of bits. They usually round, but you can use the round function.

Comment: You can also use the round function.

Comment: Thank you, but when using round function, I have to decide the decimal place for every case.

Comment: Well, it isn't an exact duplicate, the other one is in javascript. Completely different answers, for example, you can't use numpy in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy for your calculation as in below code:

```
import numpy

a=[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1]
print(numpy.sum(a))
```

Comment: why I got downvote here?
It's correct solution

Comment: Yeah, why the downvote?

Comment: This is at best hiding the problem; you were dealing with inaccurate numbers the moment you wrote `1.1` as a floating-point literal, adding them with numpy instead of the built-in `sum()` changes NOTHING.  If you had used `print` instead of a raw expression in the first place (in other words, seeing the `__str__` of the value instead of its `__repr__`), you would have gotten `7.7`, but that's just being rounded for display - the actual result isn't actually 7.7.

Answer (score 0):

This is nature of binary floating point. You can read more information [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Note: You can always use `%.f` for precision. i.e. `%.1f` in your case

Comment: Thank you for the reference.